# Mysql and Triggers usage

Tags: mysql, triggers

I wonder what's the best practice is when you have a table like this below with orders. I need to calculate the total price of each order. Should I use triggers to calculate the price or should I hardcode the calculation before insert into database?

**ORDERS:**

```
id | Article | Price | Quantity | Total price
---------------------------------------------
 1 | TV      | 5 |    1     |      5
 2 | CD      | 3 |    2     |      6
 3 | Book    | 2 |    3     |      6
 4 | XBOX    | 1 |    1     |      1
```

Comment: That depends how you want to use it, you can use either trigger or application level to do the calculation for you before insert or update. If you are comfortable with triggers then go ahead with trigger and if you think application level would be easy to do the job then do it via application level.

Comment: You should create the calculation in the application layer IMO.  Keep your business logic together.  It will be easier when the app gets more complex such as applying discounts, different tax rates, etc.